# Can Nexus OSS compress virtual OBR metadata?

Tags: osgi, nexus, sonatype, obr

I'm trying to provision a client-side swing application using OBR and Felix. It works, but even after pruning many unused bundles, the obr.xml file is still about 1MB.

That file will be downloaded many times, even though it's not *that* dynamic.

If I could gzip that file, it compresses with a factor >20, less than 50kb remains.

Can Nexus do that for me? Could I use something like:

https://nexus.dexels.com/nexus/content/groups/obr/.meta/obr.gz

instead of:

https://nexus.dexels.com/nexus/content/groups/obr/.meta/obr.xml

I can't find anything about this, and it would make a lot of sense, I think.

I'm using nexus-obr-plugin-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable gzip compression for responses by adding the following line to ${nexus_root}/conf/nexus.properties:

enable-restlet-encoder=true

If the felix client sends the "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" header then the response will be compressed.

Comment: It works fine! The Felix bundle repository doesn't supply that header though, so I'll add an issue for Felix. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an issue to the Felix bundle repository JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-3591